# SQL condition with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables BOOKS and KEYWORDS. They are bound by foreign key.

Structure of BOOKS *(Book_Id, Name, Author)*

Structure of KEYWORDS *(Key_Id, Key_Word, Book_Id)*

Now I want to get some books, in dependence what keyword is. I created command like this, but it is not showing any results.

```
select * from BOOKS 
JOIN KEYWORDS ON BOOKS.Book_Id = KEYWORDS.Book_Id 
where Author like '%a%' and KEYWORDS.Key_Word like '%a%';
```

What I am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance.
Sample Data (Sorry for that foreign language)
[image: Books]
[image: KeyWords]

EDIT : ALREADY SOLVED, but I cannot delete this question.

Comment: can you show some sample data please?

Comment: And which result do you expect?

Comment: *Greenwood* ahs no "a" in the name for id 10002 you show no author. So it is hard to see if you have any matches

Comment: My apologies. I inserted code, which was not the same as in my program. I forgot I do not have 
KeyWord like '%a%' but just KeyWord like 'a'.

Comment: so  it is working now? Than please dete the question

Comment: Yeah I would like to but :
You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if an author name and keywords matched.  I think you just want `or` fort he query:

```
select *
from BOOKS b join
     KEYWORDS k
     on b.Book_Id = k.Book_Id 
where b.Author like '%a%' or
      k.Key_Word like '%a%';
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use CTE to simplify it better.

```
with selected_keywords (book_id) as (
        select book_id from KEYWORDS
        where keyword like '%'
  ),
  select * from book 
  where book_id in (select book_id from selected_keywords)
```

We can avoid joining and filtering large datasets.

P.S : query what wrote works.

Comment: Why do u need index here? You want filter books by keywords. If keywords table and book tables are indexed then it should be fast.